# Cannot expand Ubuntu partition even though I have 22 GB of extra unallocated space

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have shrunk my Windows partition so that I can expand my Ubuntu partition. I have the following partitions:

[image: gparted screenshot]

I have booted from USB and unmounted the swap partition as well. The unallocated space is adjacent to the Linux partition `/dev/sda5`. However, when I try to expand it by right-clicking and choosing `Resize/Move`, I see the maximum partition size as only about `1.5 GB` larger:

[image]

How can I expand the Ubuntu partition to include the `22 GB` unallocated space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to expand the /dev/sda3 partition (to the left) to make it contain the unallocated space. Then you can expand the Ubuntu partition :)

Comment: This is correct, but you should probably also read through https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ExtendedPartition for information about partitioning in general